# Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and $\varphi:G \to H$ a group isomorphism. Show that if $H$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic also.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and $\varphi:G \to H$ a group isomorphism. Show that if $H$ is cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic also.

As $\varphi$ is a group isomorphism, then so is $\varphi^{-1} :H \to G$. Let $a \in H$, then $a=h^m$ for some $m \in \Bbb Z$ (as $H$ is cyclic). Since $\varphi$ is bijective there exists $g \in G$ such that $a = h^{m}=\varphi(g)$. Now applying $\varphi^{-1}$ we have that $$\varphi^{-1}(h^m) =(\varphi^{-1}(h))^m=g$$ since $g$ is arbitary we have that $\langle \varphi^{-1}(h)\rangle$ generates $G$.

Is this correct reasoning? I feel like this could be done without the usage of the inverse map.

Comment: "since $g$ is arbitrary we have ..." - you have not proved that $g$ is arbitrary. You said *given* an $h$, *there is some $g$* such that ... - you have not shown that this $g$ could in fact be any element of the group. It *is* true that the inverse of a generator is a generator, but you haven't quite proved it.

Comment: But for every $a$ there is precisely one $g$ as we're dealing with a bijection?

Comment: That might be enough to complete the argument. I think it would be easier to follow if you started with something like "Let $g \in G$ and $h$ be a generator of $H$. Then (some maths) and therefore $g = h^k$". That makes it obvious that the generator doesn't depend on the $g$ you chose, and that you really have covered every element.